# jmeter - How do I combine multiple variable arrays?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsonpath, beanshell

I have a ForEach controller where I call an endpoint to return a list of guid variables (e.g. inspectionId). I store them using JSON Extractor (JSONPath) into 1 variable - inspectionIds. Since there are multiple values, it ends up creating an array, which works perfectly when I use them down the chain on another controller. Due to the workflow requirement, I need to combine all of the instances of the inspectionIds and then move on to the next controller. But since the array is being created inside the ForEach controller, it ends up overriding on each iteration of that controller. So, I end up with the last result from the controller.

I have looked into Groovy and BeanShell Processor with no avail, so I'm asking for your help.

Here are a few screenshots -

[JSON Extractor for inspectionIds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF10f.png)

[Variable Debug Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgDkQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you placed your JSON Extractor in a wrong place, according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide)

1. If you have JSON Extractor **as a child** of the sample which returns your `inspectionIds` - it will be applied to this sampler only

   [image: JMeter Scoping Rules - child]

   In the above setup JSON Extractor is applied only to `Sampler 1`
2. If you have JSON Extractor **at the same level** as the request which returns your `inspectionId` - it will be applied to this and every other sampler in its scope (same level or below)

   [image: JMeter Scoping Rules]

   In the above setup JSON Extractor is applied to `Sampler 1` and to `Sampler 2`. Any [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) created as a result of the Sampler 1 will be **overwritten** by the Sampler 2. The same applies to [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) if you use it for your "Variable Debug" test element

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. While it would have worked perfectly if I wasn't using a ForEach controller, keeping the JSON Extractor on the same level as the controller doesn't help. I could create copies of the http request samplers and iterate it manually (the number of iterations is not the same from different test runs) versus the ForEach controller, but that would make this test quite dirty.